# jsf - Unknown Property "id" on f:param

Tags: jsf, netbeans, primefaces

Within a PrimeFaces datatable I put a `p:commandButton` in one column, which has a `p:dialog` with a `p:galleria` inside. For some reason, NetBeans could not correctly detect the object used in the `f:param` tag. Instead, it's getting the object of the datatable (`Address`).

When executing the project the galleria is working perfectly, but NetBeans sees a warning in that line and I want to get rid of it:

> Unknown Property "id"

HTML code:

```
<p:column exportable="false" colspan="1">
    <p:commandButton action="#{dashboardMB.onViewPhotosClick(address)}"
                     icon="ui-icon-image"
                     id="btn_viewphoto"
                     oncomplete="PF('dialog_photo').show();"
                     style="font-size:12px; width:100px; height:25px; display:block; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;"
                     styleClass="btn-photos"
                     title="VIEW PHOTOS"
                     update="dlg_photo"
                     value="PHOTOS">
        <p:dialog id="dlg_photo"
                  modal="true"
                  widgetVar="dialog_photo"
                  showEffect="fade"
                  hideEffect="fade"
                  resizable="false"
                  style="width:700px;"
                  header="#{address.shopName} (ID ##{address.shopId})">
            <p:galleria autoPlay="false"
                        id="dlg_photo_galleria"
                        panelHeight="313"
                        panelWidth="500"
                        showCaption="true"
                        style="border-bottom: 20px solid white;"
                        value="#{address.photos}"
                        var="photo">
                <p:graphicImage cache="false"
                                title="Operator: #{address.operator}"
                                value="#{photoMB.image}"
                                width="500">
                    <f:param name="id" value="#{photo.id}" />
                </p:graphicImage>
            </p:galleria>
        </p:dialog>
    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

EDIT:

DashboardMB getter, Address class, Photo class and the dataTable http://pastebin.com/cEyARZwf

PhotoMB http://pastebin.com/DnezFFBT

Comment: What does the object `photo` looks like? More specifically can you provide the getter and setter code of `id`?

Comment: It' an entity, but when I Ctrl+click it, NetBeans opens Address object, not Photo. Getter and setter of id: `public Integer getId() { return id; }` and `public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }`

Comment: AFAIK it is normal that the object `Address` is opened on Ctrl+click.  The var object is retrieved in the same parent object that the one specified in the attribute `value`.  Thus, it expects `photo` to be an attribute of the object `Address`.  I still don't understand why you get a warning.

Comment: I get a warning because `address.photos` is of type `List<Photo>`, so the var object is `Photo`, but I don't know why it's pointing to object `Address` - at least in the IDE.

Comment: Please show your managedbean that correspond to the view.

Comment: Edited the question. See the pastebin links.

Comment: The getter and setter for the attribute `id` in the `Photo` class are missing. Is it normal?

Comment: The getters and setters were omitted, but they're there: `public Integer getId() { return id; } public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }`

Comment: I think it must be a bug in NetBeans, because apparently the code is correct.